# Injecting properties into a QuartzJobObject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, spring.net, quartz.net

Am I right in thinking that my `QuartzJobObject` can't have any DAO's or other Spring-managed objects injected into it?

Was hoping I could do something like this (`orderService` is what I want to inject):

```xml
<object name="checkPendingOrdersJob" type="Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.JobDetailObject, Spring.Scheduling.Quartz">
  <property name="JobType" value="Munch.ScheduledTasks.CheckPendingOrdersJob" />
  <!-- We can inject values through JobDataMap -->
  <property name="JobDataAsMap">
    <dictionary>
      <!--entry key="UserName" value="Alexandre" /-->
    </dictionary>      
  </property>
  <property name="orderService" ref="orderService"/>
</object>
```

...which I know doesn't make sense because of the type it is. But, I could do with being able to inject some DAO's, Services etc somehow. I can't figure it out though. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do property/constructor injection into your job by overiding `CreateJobInstance` of
[AdaptableJobFactory](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~br=master/spring-net/src/Spring/Spring.Scheduling.Quartz/Scheduling/Quartz/AdaptableJobFactory.cs) and register your new JobFactory instead of the default one.

The passed in `TriggerFiredBundle` provides you with enough infos to ask the context for a matching job (based on conventions). `bundle.JobDetail.JobType.Name` and `bundle.JobDetail.JobType` fitted my need, so back in 2008 I ended up with sth. like this (the class is derived form `AdaptableJobFactory` and implements `IApplicationContextAware` to get the context injected):

```
public class ContextAwareJobFactory : AdaptableJobFactory, IApplicationContextAware
{
  private IApplicationContext m_Context;

  public IApplicationContext ApplicationContext
  {
    set
    {
      m_Context = value;
    }
  }

  protected override object CreateJobInstance( TriggerFiredBundle bundle )
  {
    return m_Context.GetObject( bundle.JobDetail.JobType.Name, bundle.JobDetail.JobType );
  }
}
```

You need to register the ContextAwareJobFactory using the following config:

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
  <!-- Some simple dependency -->
  <object name="SomeDependency" type="Namespace.SomeDependency, Assembly" />

  <!-- The scheduled job, gets the dependency. -->
  <object name="ExampleJob" type="Namespace.ExampleJob, Assembly" singleton="false">
    <constructor-arg name="dependency" ref="SomeDependency"/>
  </object>

  <!-- The JobDetail is configured as usual. -->
  <object name="ExampleJobDetail" type="Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.JobDetailObject, Spring.Scheduling.Quartz">
    <property name="JobType" value="Namespace.ExampleJob, Assembly"/>        
  </object>

  <!-- The new JobFactory. -->
  <object name="ContextAwareJobFactory" type="Namespace.ContextAwareJobFactory, Assembly" />

  <!-- Set the new JobFactory onto the scheduler factory. -->
  <object id="quartzSchedulerFactory" type="Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.SchedulerFactoryObject, Spring.Scheduling.Quartz">
    <property name="JobFactory" ref="ContextAwareJobFactory"/>
  </object>      
</objects>
```

I don't know if there is sth. ootb since this was developed in 2008 and I did not followed the integration progress made for quartz.net.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this, I will try it out tonight and post back my results. Cheers!

Comment: Had a play with this but couldn't quite get it to work last night (it was late though). After giving up I had a go with a methodInvokingJob that executed a method on one of my services, but then I started running into circular references with my spring context. Argh. will keep trying tonight though

Comment: Thanks guys, it works great now. I posted my version below to show the properties I set. I credited you guys in my answer but it got edited by the moderators. Thanks, very happy!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've ended up with and it works perfectly (hopefully useful to someone else)

**Job factory that is aware of Spring's context**

```
/// <summary>
/// A custom job factory that is aware of the spring context
/// </summary>
public class ContextAwareJobFactory : AdaptableJobFactory, IApplicationContextAware
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The spring app context
    /// </summary>
    private IApplicationContext m_Context;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the context
    /// </summary>
    public IApplicationContext ApplicationContext
    {
        set
        {
            m_Context = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overrides the default version and sets the context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bundle"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override object CreateJobInstance(TriggerFiredBundle bundle)
    {
        return m_Context.GetObject(bundle.JobDetail.JobType.Name, bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }
}
```

**The job itself** (checks the DB for records and if there are at least *HomeManyMenuItemsIsOK* of them, everything is good). Note: menuService is an injected spring-managed object that itself has several DAO's in it). HowManyMenuItemsIsOK is a static property that's passed in through the job data map.

```
public class CheckMenuIsHealthyJob : QuartzJobObject 
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CheckMenuIsHealthyJob));

    public IMenuService menuService { get; set; }
    public int HowManyMenuItemsIsOK { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check how healthy the menu is by seeing how many menu items are stored in the database. If there
    /// are more than 'HowManyMenuItemsIsOK' then we're ok.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    protected override void ExecuteInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        IList<MenuItem> items = menuService.GetAllMenuItems();
        if (items != null && items.Count >= HowManyMenuItemsIsOK)
        {
            log.Debug("There are " + items.Count + " menu items. Menu is healthy!");
        }
        else
        {
            log.Warn("Menu needs some menu items adding!");
        }

    }
}
```

**And  finally the Spring config**

```xml
<!-- Scheduled Services using Quartz -->
  <!-- This section contains Quartz config that can be reused by all our Scheduled Tasks ---->  
  <!-- The Quartz scheduler factory -->
  <object id="quartzSchedulerFactory" type="Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.SchedulerFactoryObject, Spring.Scheduling.Quartz">
    <!-- Tell Quartz to use our custom (context-aware) job factory -->
    <property name="JobFactory" ref="contextAwareJobFactory"/>

    <!-- Register the triggers -->
    <property name="triggers">
      <list>
        <ref object="frequentTrigger" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>  

  <!-- Funky new context-aware job factory -->
  <object name="contextAwareJobFactory" type="Munch.Service.ScheduledTasks.ContextAwareJobFactory" />

  <!-- A trigger that fires every 10 seconds (can be reused by any jobs that want to fire every 10 seconds) -->
  <object id="frequentTrigger" type="Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.CronTriggerObject, Spring.Scheduling.Quartz" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="checkMenuIsHealthyJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpressionString" value="0/10 * * * * ?" />
  </object>  

  <!-- Now the job-specific stuff (two object definitions per job; 1) the job and 2) the job detail) --> 
  <!-- Configuration for the 'check menu is healthy job' -->
  <!-- 1) The job -->
  <object name="checkMenuIsHealthyJob" type="Munch.Service.ScheduledTasks.CheckMenuIsHealthyJob" singleton="false">
    <property name="menuService" ref="menuService"/>
  </object>

  <!-- 2) The job detail -->
  <object name="checkMenuIsHealthyJobDetail" type="Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.JobDetailObject, Spring.Scheduling.Quartz">
    <property name="JobType" value="Munch.Service.ScheduledTasks.CheckMenuIsHealthyJob"/>
    <property name="JobDataAsMap">
      <dictionary>
        <entry key="HowManyMenuItemsIsOK" value="20" />
      </dictionary>
    </property>    
  </object>
```